# Is it common to say "the more is true"?

Tags: grammar

[From a post](https://www.reddit.com/r/howyoudoin/comments/4f3z9w/monica_really_is_the_glue_that_holds_the_group/)

> S09E03 The One With the Pediatrician, Ross says "You can't go. I mean, you're the glue that holds the group together." about Monica.

> The more I think about it, **the more is true** ...

I guess I understand the meaning, that is, the poster strongly agrees with what Ross says.

However, [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&year_start=1900&case_insensitive=on&content=the%20more%20is%20true&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=) shows no writer says it that way

[image]

Is it missing something grammatically?

Comment: You used the wrong [Ngram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+more+is+true&corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20more%20is%20true%3B%2Cc0). Although that's the wrong expression for that context, *the more is true* ***is*** a valid expression in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence looks like a typo. The writer probably meant "the more it's true," which is to say "it becomes more true when I think about it more."

Furthermore, they probably *actually* meant something like "the more it seems true," or "the more I realize it's true," as thinking about something doesn't generally change its truth value. This kind of elision is common in informal speech, but still wrong.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a typo